# How to intercept the “Cannot play video” dialog while working with streaming or networked video?

Tags: video, streaming, android-mediaplayer

How to intercept the "Cannot play video" dialog while working with streaming or networked video?

I tried the following and was able to display my custom error message. But on top of that I am still getting Android MediaPlayer error dialog "Cannot play video".

I have implemented `setOnErrorListener` for MediaPlayer and overwrote the `onError` method with logic to show my error message and I am returning `true` to let Android know I am handling this error. My code is as follows

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (!mediaActivity.isFinishing()) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            showErrorDialog(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the my working code!

```
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewPopup);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(this.mediaURL); // Put your URL here
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Utils.showAlertDialog(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_MESSAGE, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, VideoPopupActivity.this);
            return true;
        }
    });

    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James but you are doing exactly the same what I am doing i.e. capturing the onError and displaying our own custom dialog and return true.